# How to set LOCALE_PATH relative to project path in Django?

Tags: django, django-i18n

In the development environment, I set locale paths to:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
'/Users/***/Documents/Projects/**/Server/Django/**/locale',
)
```

But when I deploy it to server, locale path shold be changed.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

to settings add

```
import os

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "locale"),
)
```

Answer (score 6):

I am still currently using Django 1.5 and have found that I can handle it the easiest with the following:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    'locale',
)
```

The following works better if you need to use an absolute path (indentation emphasized on purpose):

```
import os.path

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.abspath(
        os.path.join(
            os.path.dirname(__file__), 
                '..', "locale")),
)
```

- First, the call to `os.path.dirname` returns the path to the directory of the settings file (`__file__`), e.g. `/Users/foobar/projects/django-tutorial/mysite/mysite`
- Next, the call to `os.path.join` joins the previous result with a relative reference to a `locale` directory one level higher, e.g. `/Users/foobar/projects/django-tutorial/mysite/mysite/../locale`
- Last, the call to `os.path.abspath` transforms the previous relative path reference to an absolute one, e.g. `/Users/foobar/projects/django-tutorial/mysite/locale`